# Group classes that are based on a template?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, variadic-templates

I don't want to shoot myself in the foot, so I will provide a little context in case this is an XY problem and there is a better way to deal with this.

I have a lot of data in a lot of binary files; these data come from various hardware, so I have data in `int`, `float`, `double`, `long double`, etc.

These data have a header to identify where it comes from (which equipment), type of data (`int`, `double`, etc.) what was being done when the data was obtained (physics run, calibration, testing, etc), and other things.

The best, and most intuitive way, to handle these data I have thought about is the following:

Have a `Header` class that gives the information about the data:

```cpp
class Header {
    public:
        int event_id;
        int time_stamp;
        int data_size;
        int trigger_mask;
};
```

And then have a class template for the data (header plus a vector containing the actual data):

```cpp
template<class T> class Data {
    public:
        Header data_header;
        std::vector<T> values;
};
```

The problem is that people might want to, depending on the analysis they want to do, group different `Data<X>` objects. The easiest example would be if people want to group the data (same type) collected by all the `EQUIPMENT X`s.

```cpp
std::vector<Data<double>> x_signals;
```

But, what if people want to group all the data produced by `EQUIPMENT X` and loop through it? This is not necessarily all of the same type, the same equipment can throw some data in `double` for some things, and some other data in `int`.

Another case would be when people are reading the `Data` objects from the binary file. They may want to have a `std::vector<Data>` and push into it the data as they read from the file. But this also wouldn't be possible.

The possible solutions I have though about are:

1. Do nothing, and it would be the user's problem in how to handle these `Data` objects. They could have, eg:

   ```cpp
   std::vector<Data<int>> int_data;
   std::vector<Data<double>> double_data;
   std::vector<Data<float>> float data;
   ```

   And then they can push the `Data` they read into the correct container. If they want the `Data` with a specific characteristic (event_id, time_stamp, etc), they would have to loop through all the containers above (and maybe store the indices of the data they want somewhere else).
2. Provide a variadic template that keeps different `Data` types in a tuple:

   ```cpp
   template<class ...Types> class DataPack {
       public:
           std::tuple<Types...> data_pack;
   };
   ```

   But this would require the number of `Data` objects to be known beforehand for a `DataPack`. We couldn't push `Data` into a `DataPack` as we read the file, and there is no way we can know how many `Data` objects we collected before we read the file.
3. Make `Data` inherit from `Header`. This way we can have vectors of "headers" and use polymorphism. The problem is that `Data` **is not a type of** header; `Data` **has a** header. Inheritance feels weird and non-intuitive, which is a bit of a red flag.

I am a bit confused, and I don't know what the best approach would be. Am I thinking about all of this in the wrong way? All three options seem to have a different degree of *ugliness*; I don't feel happy or confident with any of them.

Comment: Possibly use the visitor pattern and a `std::variant`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not think OP needs double dispatch here. It looks like a simple `std::variant` will suffice.

Comment: @NathanOliver could you expand a little bit (maybe in an answer) about your suggestion? I am not familiar with `std::variant`, but if I understood correctly your suggestion is to change the template `std::vector<T>` in my `Data` for e.g. `std::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>>`? Would this allow me to have e.g. a `std::vector<Data>`? Or what is the suggestion with regard to grouping data?

Comment: @PhysicsPDF I was more thinking you'd have a `std::vector<std::variant<Data<T>, Data<U>, ..., Data<N>>>`

Comment: @NathanOliver So if I understood correctly; your suggestion is option number 1 (do nothing, and keep the class template)? With this `Data` design people can, if they wanted to, still group them with a `std::vector` of `std::variant` as you suggest. Other less `C++ fluent` people (like myself) will still do what I suggested (different vectors for each type), but that is their problem and not mine. Is this correct?

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if I'm fully understanding your problem but here is my attempt. Have a class which holds everything: data, machine, data types, etc. Add accessor functions for people to retrieve the data and cast as needed.

```
#include <vector>

enum class EquipmentType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    VoltMeter = 1,
    CurrentMeter = 2
};

enum class DataType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    INT = 1,
    DOUBLE = 2
};

class Data
{
public:
    Data();
    
    EquipmentType GetType() { return m_type; }
    
    int GetInt()
    {
        switch(m_dType)
        {
            case DataType::INT:     return m_nValue;
            case DataType::DOUBLE:  return static_cast<int>(m_dValue);
        }
    }
    
    double GetDouble()
    {
        switch(m_dType)
        {
            case DataType::INT:     return static_cast<double>(m_nValue);
            case DataType::DOUBLE:  return m_dValue;
        }
    }
private:
    int m_nValue;
    double m_dValue;
    std::vector<char> m_vValue;
    EquipmentType m_type;
    DataType m_dType;
};
```

The above is a really brief idea of what to do. Basically each class can store every type of data. When someone calls, for example, `GetInt()` you return the correct value based upon the type of data you're holding: sometimes you'll need to cast the data. I left out the `vector` solution because I don't feel like typing it all up. This approach will allow you to store any data type and return based upon what the user requests. They can also search an array of classes and look for a specific equipment type by calling `GetType()` and seeing if it matches what they want for a comparison:

```
std::vector<Data> dataObject;

for(auto& obj : dataObject)
{
    if(obj.GetType() == EquipmentType::VoltMeter)
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
}
```

This is all a rough outline but should give you an idea.

Comment: Why are you trying to reimplement the poor man's `std::variant`?

Comment: @SergeyA: Because a `std::variant` is a union and is cast once used. If someone wants to change data types an exception is thrown. This data object removes that. I'll admit, I haven't played around with `std::variant` so I may be missing some subtleties.

Comment: Indeed you are. One can change the value of the variant to any type the variant supports at any time, otherwise it would be quite a limiting type.